# Search Box populate "suggestions" as user types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to create a "Rate my class" similar to rate my professor, for a school project. I would like users to enter text in a search box, and similar to Google, I wish it to "guess" or have "suggestions" based on what they have typed so far.

Example: user types "MG" ... below the search box I would like options to show up such as "MGMT3000"
"MGMT5080"

etc.

Does anyone know how to perform this (if it is jQuery/JavaScript, please let me know where to get them or give me a reference please!)? Note: I am connecting to SQL Server and I'm not sure how to connect the search box to search the attributes of Course_Tbl thus far. I used the LoginView tool to create the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the jQueryUI autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

But the AJAX Control Toolkit would probably be easier to connect to a database.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

--EDIT--

Installing AJAX Control Toolkit with NuGet:

Open NuGet:
Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

Finding AJAX Control Toolkit:
Expand 'Online' in left panel
Search for 'AJAX Control Toolkit' in upper righthand corner
Click 'Install'

---- This will install the package and all of its dependencies in the correct locations, but only for this specific project. You will need to repeat these steps for each project you wish to include the toolkit

You should be good to use the control now. Just begin typing ajax and intellisense should list all of the options that come with the toolkit. The control you're looking for is the ajaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender

Comment: Thanks m3h2014, I will investigate this further.

Comment: You're welcome. I've implemented the AJAX AutoComplete on an .NET web app before. The implementation is not very complicated. And you can easily add the toolkit to your project using NuGet through VS.

Comment: My experience in VS is pretty much using the toolkit and drag and drop. Pretty pathetic - so a walkthrough would be fantastic.

Comment: I edited my original answer to include some quick instructions for installing the package with NuGet.

Comment: I greatly appreciate it. You have helped me a lot. I also found a great video tutorial for connecting to a data source. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try out KendoUI - http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html . They have a lot of examples how to bind to a database etc. Just look into their documentation.

Comment: Great reference, thank you Georgi-it.